# What's going wrong with my AWS domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, cloudflare

I registered a domain with AWS, but I have my server at Heroku and wanted to use CloudFlare with it. So I set out to set this up. I now have my nameservers pointing to `tim.ns.cloudflare.com` and `thomas.ns.cloudflare.com`. There's also a SOA record pointing to some Amazon stuff. On CloudFlare, I have my domain pointing to myapp.herokuapp.com.

However, when I visited the domain, I get an error saying `Safari can't open the page, because Safari can't find the server`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I now have a CNAME record pointing to tim.ns.cloudflare.com and thomas.ns.cloudflare.com." Why would you do that? Those are nameservers. You need to change your domain to use them as its nameservers. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html

Comment: Sorry, my bad. That's what I meant to type. Brainfart.

Comment: What's the domain name?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should verify that the name is actually resolving properly. For example, on Unix, you may execute the following command:

```
    dig @tim.ns.cloudflare.com yourdomain
```

This command basically ask the name server mentioned for the A record of your domain directly. Make sure it matches what you have set in Cloudflare.

If that looks alright, try to clear the DNS cache on your computer. For example, in OSX Yosemite, you may do that using this command:

```
    sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

If that still does not work, compare the previous `dig` result with this:

```
    dig yourdomain
```

The difference is this ask for the A record from the name resolver of your network, such as your home router, ISP's resolver, whatever. If the two results do not match, you either need to wait for cached record to expire or force it to clear the cached record.